# Ubuntu apache ssl issues

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I am a little confused about what is going on here. I've tried to diagnose the situation with Google to no avail. I want to get this working as well as understand what is wrong. Basically I am trying to enable ssl on a remote ubuntu 11.10 apache server. I'm currently using the snakeoil certs just to get everything working and then I will switch to a trusted cert. Scanning 443 shows that it is open on the server.

When I ssh in and run this command

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

everything looks fine. But when I run this command remotely

```
openssl s_client -connect www.mydomain.com:443
```

I get this error

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
10576:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:607:
```

The port is open and being forwarded correctly. What gives?

Comment: Have you tried to do a simple tcpdump?  Do you see the packets from the remote system?  Does it do a TCP hand-shake?

Comment: Try opening http://www.mydomain.com:443/ in a web browser to see if perhaps apache is serving http on the https port for that ip address.

Comment: Yeah, something's out of whack - `tcpdump` is a good place to look.  Is it trying to hit the correct interface IP when `www.mydomain.com` is resolved - or is it a public address that's NAT'd to an interface IP?

Comment: What do you mean by "The port is open and being forwarded correctly"?  Is there some other layer between the Internet and your web server?

Comment: Can you show the VirtualHost and NameVirtualHost configurations?